# ConnectedRouter - push a route programatically with browser back functionality

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am using ConnectedRouter from react-router-redux (5.0.0-alpha.6). Here is sample code

```
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={app.store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={app.history}>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route exact path="/:animalName?" component={Animalpage} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have a requirement where if I am landing on "/" then it should route to a default animal (say Cat).

I am achieving this using push from react-router-redux

```
dispatch(push("/Cat"));
```

Now problem is when I hit browser back button, it is taking me to "/" which is again taking me back to "/Cat" and hence I am unable to use back button from browser.

Is there a way to achieve my requirement to go to default route and have browser back button work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `replace()` action rather than `push()`. Detail information can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward)

> Action creators that correspond with the [history methods of the same
>   name](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v3/docs/GettingStarted.md#navigation).
>   For reference they are defined as follows:
>
> - **push** - Pushes a new location to history, becoming the current location.
> - **replace** - Replaces the current location in history.
> - **go** - Moves backwards or forwards a relative number of locations in history.
> - **goForward** - Moves forward one location. Equivalent to go(1)
> - **goBack** - Moves backwards one location. Equivalent to go(-1)